# Не удается подставить переменную в регулярку

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
const str = 'ssss ssss ssss tmp tmp'
const vl = 'tmp'
console.log(str.replace(/tmp$/i, 'новая строка'))
```

Как подставить переменную 'vl' В данную регулярку?

Comment: Извините, но Вы принципиально не читаете [документацию](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-introduction#regulyarnye-vyrazheniya)? Уже не первый ваш вопрос по регулярным выражениям, но прогресс нулевой.

Comment: @Лена Просмотрел ваши вопросы на данном сайте, проанализировав их, я абсолютно согласен с комментарием выше. Вам стоит найти ментора либо найти исполнителя для ваших задач.

Comment: @NowhereMan, в этом вопросе принятый ответ очень не хорош. Работает пока в переменную не попадёт метасимвол.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как подставить переменную `vl` В данную регулярку?

Если в значении переменной нет "управляющих символов" - то довольно просто.

```js
const str = 'ssss ssss ssss tmp tmp'
const vl = 'tmp'
const re = new RegExp(vl + '$', 'i')
console.log(str.replace(re, 'новая строка'))
```

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, добавил `$`... Если есть метасимволы - их придется экранировать.

Answer (score 1):

Если в переменной `vl` окажется какой-нибудь метасимвол, то замена сломается. Вам понадобится функция `escapeRegExp` чтобы "экранировать" метасимволы, то есть заставить их вести себя как обычные символы.

***NB** Метасимволы перечислены в регулярном выражении внутри `escapeRegExp`*.

Регулярное выражение `/tmp$/i` надо заменить на `new RegExp(escapeRegExp(vl) + '$', 'i')`. Так можно собрать текст образца из строк.

```
const escapeRegExp = re => re.replace(/[\\^$.*+?()[\]{}|]/g, '\\$&');

const str = 'ssss ssss ssss tmp tmp';
const vl = 'tmp';
console.log(str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(vl) + '$', 'i'), 'новая строка'))
```